# Create a new file in Filezilla folder?

Tags: windows, filezilla

I can see a "New Folder" menu but no "New File".
Is this impossible or any Filezilla alternative that can do so?

Answer (score 5):

I have not seen any FTP client that has this feature - your best bet is simply to create a temp folder somewhere on your machine and have a 0KB file (right click, New > Text File) and rename it to whatever you want. You can then upload this file to wherever you want and it basically will do the same job as a "New File"

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu but I guess this will work on windows as well.
In the bottom right of the screen where you see the directory listing, if you right click on any file, there is an option called create new file, which will serve the purpose!

[image: Click here to view the screenshot]